# reusing controller actions from various other places in website

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The common situation when developing a website is to have one index action that lists and creates multiple different resources.

For example, lets say that you have transactions controller that lists both payments and expenses on same page (where expense is an auto-calculated group of payments).

On transactions index action, there are two forms: one for creating new expense, and the other for creating new payment. Both of these forms point to submits to their respective controllers create action. If the data is invalid, it should redirect back to transactions#index and display error messages.

This is just a general discussion, it is not related to specific problem, so lets assumpt the following:

- No AJAX will be used
- We cannot generalize expenses and payments into shared base

The problem is that while we can submit data to different controller, we can't get response from it. We can redirect back, but then we'll loose our data and validation errors. There are some 'hackish' solutions to this, but I would like to keep this simple.

One way of solving this would be to implement specific actions on transactions controller (like create_expense and create_payment). It would work, but it would cause code duplication and breaking of REST and I dont like it.

The real question is: how can we re-use controller actions from various other places in website, and make it feel like a natural process?

Answer (score 1):

You could include a `hidden_field :redirect_back_to => transactions_path` in your forms, and then just post the forms to their respective controllers, and let the controllers redirect back to `params[:redirect_back_to]` if it's present.

This might seem a bit hacky, but I think it's the easiest solution if you don't want to use AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While it would solve redirection, it does not solve validation and pre-populating the form. I am already using `redirect_to :back` with error message as an flash alert, but it will clear out the form and wont display validation messages the usual way. I'm looking for something more elegant..